# JBOSS - failed to execute goal, redeploy failed

Tags: java, maven, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy an EJB as an EAR to my WildFly Server, and I can't deploy. 
I read that it could be something related to the Maven Dependency known as Cargo Container, and updating it should help. I've tried several versions and it doesn't work.

I'm not sure if I understand everything entirely, but here's my Maven Error:

```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.1:redeploy (cargo-prep) on project basicejb-test: Execution cargo-prep of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.1:redeploy failed: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.1:redeploy (cargo-prep) on project basicejb-test: Execution cargo-prep of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.1:redeploy failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution cargo-prep of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.1:redeploy failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField (HttpURLConnection.java:3093)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:489)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.internal.http.HttpConnection.connect (HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.internal.http.HttpConnection.post (HttpConnection.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.internal.http.request.HttpFormRequest.execute (HttpFormRequest.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.wildfly.internal.AbstractWildFlyRemoteDeployer.uploadDeployable (AbstractWildFlyRemoteDeployer.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.wildfly.internal.AbstractWildFlyRemoteDeployer.deploy (AbstractWildFlyRemoteDeployer.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.redeploy (AbstractDeployer.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.DeployerRedeployMojo.performDeployerActionOnSingleDeployable (DeployerRedeployMojo.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.performDeployerActionOnAllDeployables (AbstractDeployerMojo.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.doExecute (AbstractDeployerMojo.java:98)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute (AbstractCargoMojo.java:471)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.internal.http.HttpConnection$1.getPasswordAuthentication (HttpConnection.java:136)
    at java.net.Authenticator.requestPasswordAuthentication (Authenticator.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$1.run (HttpURLConnection.java:454)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$1.run (HttpURLConnection.java:449)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.privilegedRequestPasswordAuthentication (HttpURLConnection.java:448)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getServerAuthentication (HttpURLConnection.java:2453)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1743)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.internal.http.HttpConnection.connect (HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.internal.http.HttpConnection.post (HttpConnection.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.internal.http.request.HttpFormRequest.execute (HttpFormRequest.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.wildfly.internal.AbstractWildFlyRemoteDeployer.uploadDeployable (AbstractWildFlyRemoteDeployer.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.wildfly.internal.AbstractWildFlyRemoteDeployer.deploy (AbstractWildFlyRemoteDeployer.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.redeploy (AbstractDeployer.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.DeployerRedeployMojo.performDeployerActionOnSingleDeployable (DeployerRedeployMojo.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.performDeployerActionOnAllDeployables (AbstractDeployerMojo.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.doExecute (AbstractDeployerMojo.java:98)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute (AbstractCargoMojo.java:471)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

I'm using this cargo dependency as of now:

```
<cargo-maven2-plugin.version>1.7.1</cargo-maven2-plugin.version>
<cargo.containerId>wildfly9x</cargo.containerId>
<wildfly-controller-client.version>8.2.1.Final</wildfly-controller-client.version>
```

I'm also using WildFly 17, is this important when declaring the cargo.containerId?

Comment: You should start with the correct Maven Archetype for your project. This will create the correct structure for your project. The EJB is packaged inside the EAR

Comment: Can I somehow convert my current project within Intellij? What Maven Archetype do you recommend?

Comment: Consider using the [WildFly Maven Plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/) instead of cargo for your deployments. Alternatively, set your `cargo.containerId` to `wildfly17x` and maybe update `cargo-maven2-plugin.version` to 1.7.7

Comment: Should I deploy an EAR to the server? My current tutorial doesn't really specify this but I just had a realisation that this might be where it's going wrong.
I tried making a seperate project, and there deploying a war project with litterally nothing, except for a JBOSS Config, and this didn't work for me either. 
Or is this supposed ot be done with the cargo Container/Cargo Maven plugin?

This is done with Intellij btw.